# Allow location sharing popup after change from one map view in TileLayer to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

After I change map in TileLayer from mapUrl to sateliteMapUrl even when popup asking about location was denied it is asking about location again. Could you give me some hints or ideas how to solve it?

Here is gif representing problem.
[GIF Representing described problem](https://giphy.com/gifs/YEkYcY51HOHo2GpNsT/fullscreen)

```js
import { useMap } from "react-leaflet/hooks";
import Switch from "@mui/material/Switch";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { useStore } from "../stores/store";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, useMapEvents } from "react-leaflet";
import Control from "react-leaflet-custom-control";

  
  const { appStore } = useStore();
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const sateliteMapUrl = "https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}";
  const mapUrl =
    "https://tile.thunderforest.com/atlas/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey={APIKEY}";

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      function (position) {
        appStore.setCoordinates([
          position.coords.latitude,
          position.coords.longitude,
        ]);
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );

    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.setUrl(appStore.sateliteView ? sateliteMapUrl : mapUrl);
    }
  }, [appStore.sateliteView, appStore]);
  
  
<MapContainer
  center={appStore.coordinates}
  zoom={13}
  zoomControl={false}
  scrollWheelZoom={true}
>
  <TileLayer
    ref={ref}
    url={appStore.sateliteView ? sateliteMapUrl : mapUrl}
    subdomains={["mt1", "mt2", "mt3"]}
  />
  <Control>
    <FormControlLabel
      control={
        <Switch
          color="warning"
          checked={appStore.sateliteView}
          onChange={(e) => {
            appStore.setSateliteView(e.target.checked);
          }}
        />
      }
      label={<Typography variant="h3">Satellite</Typography>}
    />
  </Control>
</MapContainer>
```

Comment: empty the dep array and it should work

Comment: It helped. Thanks! 
I have to diveded it into two useEffect functions with different dependency arrays.